# Problema de responsividad en Datatable al momento de llamar a Ajax para ingresar las tablas / columnas

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, datatable, adminlte

necesito ayuda con un problema que estoy presentando en un proyecto al momento de introducir datatable con Ajax, resulta que cuando llamo a DataTable con JavaScript todo funciona bien, trabaja de manera responsive, pero automaticamente llamo a Ajax y pongo las columnas correspondientes, ya no es responsive la datatable. Ahora les presentaré las imagenes a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

En la primera imagen se observa ya el Datatable funcionando al llamarlo con JS pero automaticamente introduzco "ajax" y todas sus propiedas, y luego las columnas, ya no me funciona igual el Datatable no es responsivo. Ahí está el código tambien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var opcion;

    tablaUsuarios = $('#tablausuarios').DataTable({
        "language": {
            "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
        },
        "ajax":{
            "url": "config/crud.php",
            "method": "POST" //usamos el metodo POST
        },
        "columns":[
            {"data": "id"},
            {"data": "nombre"},
            {"data": "usuario"},
            {"data": "email"},
            {"data": "nombre_grupo"},
            {"data": "estado"},
            {"data": "fecha_registro"},
            {"defaultContent": "<a title='Editar Usuario' class='badge badge-info'><i style='color:white' class='fa fa-edit'></i></a><a title='Eliminar Usuario' class='badge badge-danger'><i style='color:white' class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>"}
        ]
    });
});
```

Código HTML

```
<?php
    $menu[02] = 1;
    require "plantillas/header.php";
?>

<div class="content-wrapper">
    <div class="content-header">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row mb-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <!--h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Starter Page</h1-->
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><button id="nuevousuario" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm form-control" data-toggle="modal"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Nuevo</button></li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h1 class="card-title">Lista de Usuarios</h1>
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="tablausuarios">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>ID</th>
                                            <th>Nombre Completo</th>
                                            <th>Usuario</th>
                                            <th>E-Mail</th>
                                            <th>Grupo</th>
                                            <th>Estado</th>
                                            <th>Agregado</th>
                                            <th>Acciones</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalusuarios" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dimiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            </div>
            <form id="formulario_usuarios">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="nombres">Nombres</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nombres" name="nombres">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="apellidos">Apellidos</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="correo">Correo</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="correo" name="correo" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="usuario" name="usuario" >
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <label for="password">Contraseña</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="grupo">Grupo</label>
                                <select class="form-control" name="grupo" id="grupo" >
                                    <option>Seleccionar...</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="cestado">Estado</label>
                                <select class="form-control" id="estado" name="estado">
                                    <option>Seleccionar...</option>
                                    <option>Activo</option>
                                    <option>Inactivo</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="guardar" id="guardar" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php require "plantillas/footer.php"; ?>
```

Comment: ¿Cómo es tu HTML de la tabla?

Comment: Ahí agregué el HTML

Comment: Agrega el atributo `width` en la etiqueta `table`. Además, creo que `datatable` tiene la clase `dt-responsive`. Debería quedarte algo así:  `<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" id="tablausuarios" width="100%">`. Prueba con una primero, luego con la otra y luego con ambas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, he solucionado el problema, agregué el atributo width a la etiqueta table

Comment: @DjCrazy sé que es una pregunta antigua, pero por favor, añade eso como respuesta. De ese modo ganarás una medalla especial del sitio (nigromante) y la publicación quedará completa.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario @AlvaroMontoro . Ya publiqué la respuesta, la verdad no sé porque no lo hice en su momento.

Answer (score 1):

Agrega el atributo `width` en la etiqueta `table`.

Además, creo que `datatables` o `bootstrap` tiene la clase `dt-responsive`. Debería quedarte algo así:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive" id="tablausuarios" width="100%">
```

Prueba con una primero, luego con la otra y luego con ambas.

Answer (score 0):

Si funciono colocarle `dt-responsive` y el `width=100%`

Comment: ¿Por qué funcionó? ¿Colocarlo en dónde?

Comment: Probablemente hiciste referencia a [este comentario](/q/342164#comment619210_342164). ¡Cítalo en tu respuesta! Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.